# Lost files for my app, but still have key. Can I still update my app?

Tags: android-studio

I have an app on the google play store that's getting around 3k downloads a day. Recently I tried sharing my files through google drive and they all got screwed up and won't work in Android Studio when I open them. Is it possible for me to start from scratch and submit that update to the listing I already have? All I'd like to do is place some ads into the app

I still have the key for the file I believe.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can still sign a new version of the app so long as you have the original key and passcode (if you used one).

Submitting successfully will also require you to have the same package name and a version number higher than your last release.

Comment: Is there a way of finding out which key I used? This was the first app I ever created and I constantly named the keys "Key.jks"

Comment: I don’t believe so. That would somewhat defeat the purpose of the key. Most likely the only way to know will be to prepare signed versions with each of the keys and test uploading them as APKs to the Google developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find the answer! Turns out I can create a new android studio project with the same package names and sign with the old key.